# Re-focus on the button

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Re-focus on the button

When you first clicked, triggers: focus,
but no clicks during the following as the focus remained still. Question - how to make the event worked with every click?

My code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/c06wr71w/)

```css
body { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3F51B5;
  color: #eee;
  transition: all .2s;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: btn .7s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes btn {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 0 rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 20px rgba(63, 81, 181, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>name button</button>
```

I would be glad of any help. Thank you

Comment: You might need java script or jQuery to do that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/z5gb5frq/)**

it can be done with a little JQ to add and remove  class `.animated`

the `setTimeout` is used to delay the toggle between class `.animated` and no class ( `700` value is the duration of your animation `.7s` )

i used `addClass` and `removeClass` with `setTimeout` instead of `toggleClass` because using `toggleClass` adds and removes the class instantly and the animation has no time to load

code CSS :

```
.animated{
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: btn .7s ease-in-out;

 }
```

JQ :

```
$('button').click(function() {
var anim = $(this).addClass('animated');
setTimeout(function() {
     anim.removeClass('animated');
}, 700);
});
```